# Possible DApp infrastructure on Cardano. Interaction with users' wallets

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, wallet, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to build a possible DApp infrastructure on Cardano in my head.

We should write the validation script in Haskell. Also as I understand, it is suggested to use Haskell for the off-chain code that will generate/spend UTXOs.

Okay.

We have as called "endpoints" - special Monads that can connect real wallets to the DApp.
I guess these "endpoints" could be brought into the DApp frontend somehow.
Yes?

But I still cannot understand how to connect these "endpoints" to the real users' wallets? So far we have examples with test wallets.

And is it feasible to build all necessary off-chain parts in Haskell or nobody really does it? If not, how it is supposed to be done? I mean to be connected to the real users' wallets, build and submit or spend UTXOs?

Probably the PAB aims to solve this, but it is not ready yet.
What is the real state of the art now for me as a developer?

These posts are relevant, but it looks like no solution today:

[How does DApp front-end integrate with user wallets?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/how-does-dapp-front-end-integrate-with-user-wallets?rq=1)

[How to connect wallet with my dapps using yoroi dapp connector.?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/how-to-connect-wallet-with-my-dapps-using-yoroi-dapp-connector?rq=1)

[How does a Cardano DApp client authorize a payment?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/how-does-a-cardano-dapp-client-authorize-a-payment?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using the cardano-serialization-lib and ReactJs. I had a lot of the same questions until I decided to work through an example eventually created a gitrepo

Cardano-serialization-lib is the way to go if you want to write focus on Plutus On Chain code (and do as little as possible, or none Plutus off chain code)

https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector

A working demo is here:

https://dynamicstrategies.io/wconnector

Answer (score 0):

The only way i have found is to do everything the PAB will do with Cardano Serialization Lib. You could do it with Cardano Cli etc... but UTXO model is not easy to implement in none of the above mentionated options. After all everything in the blockchain are just transactions... even smart contracts are just transaction with reedemers and datum and contracts in them. Any tool for generating transactions can in theory do the job. The only thing you need is a way to interact in a secure way with the user prvKeys, so that users  are in total control, only signing what the dApp asks to. This last option is already available with some light Wallets like Nami, CCVault... and i have read that even Yoroi.

Answer (score 0):

The PAB's original main use case was to interact with Daedalus (see [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/249#issuecomment-1041364582)). In this setup the PAB generates an unbalanced transaction that is passed to Daedalus for balancing and submission. The dApp infrastructure here would consist of (i) a frontend to accept user interaction, (ii) the PAB (including the chain index) for constructing the unbalanced transaction, and (iii) a Cardano node to which the PAB is connected. A list of the possible infrastructures can be found here: https://plutus-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/explanations/pab.html

With browser wallets the story is different. Browser wallets can't balance transactions as of early 2022. So, unfortunately, the current standard way to interact with them is to pass a balanced transaction to the browser wallet and have it sign it. To construct this balanced transaction there seem to be a multitude of ways currently deployed. Some use custom code that makes use of the available Cardano CLIs such as Cardano Wallet. A useful fork is apparently [MELD](https://github.com/MELD-labs/cardano-wallet/commits/master).

I have written a high level, opinionated blog post on the current state of browser wallet integrations [here](https://jeyeins.substack.com/p/we-need-better-wallets-on-cardano?utm_source=url).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, many DApps construct unsigned transactions either directly from browser using [Cardano-serialization-lib](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib) (it can compile to WASM) or from backend server using Cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-cli, or PAB. Once the unsigned transaction is created, its CBOR is sent to wallet for signing. Finally, the signature/witness are inserted back to the transaction so it become a signed transaction, which could then be submitted to the blockchain network either by the wallet itself or by backend server.

[Here](https://github.com/cffls/pycardano/tree/main/examples/full_stack) is a simple end-to-end working example that construct transactions using [PyCardano](https://github.com/cffls/pycardano) and have user to sign transactions with Nami wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Typhon Wallet Dapp connector takes away extra load of fetching UTXOs, building a transaction in your front-end application.

You just need to specify to which address you want to send ada/tokens to and work of building a transaction and submitting will be done by typhon wallet.

Below is an example code snippet,

```
const paymentTransactionResponse = await window.cardano.typhon.paymentTransaction({
  outputs: [
    {
      address:
        "addr_test1qz7jw975stagnvs00wsjny6y6gpazn86yvwcm2vy02j3up7mt68vuzvz4nzgs00x0shrgywvy674v6r2zcs8fxvvq27qfjq8np",
      amount: "6000000",
    },
  ],
});
```

More Examples, https://docs.typhonwallet.io/examples/paymentTransaction.html#sending-ada