# Can someone show me how to get the transaction in the proper format for cip-30?

Tags: transaction, cbor, nami, cip

I have generate a transaction using cardano-cli and I am trying to get Nami wallet to sign the transaction.

The command to build the transaction

> cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
> --fee 0 
> --tx-in $browserTxHash#$browserTxIx 
> --tx-out ${desktopAddress}+5000000 
> --tx-out ${browserAddress}+10000000 
> --out-file transaction.raw

Which writes the following to the file "transaction.raw"

> {
> "type": "TxBodyAlonzo",
> "description": "",
> "cborHex": "86a50081825820e34a60ee397dee115b75379af692962dabc085bed002fc0371e578ebd27acd62000d80018282581d60bf1466152d256eb5e8b490c5febc029593f0e9a5b9ee270d75ba35491a004c4b4082583900d9cdd3ead63bd0db91bd83cfa9f3d588bb05a3fb487d5eb62946672cbfcbf21db7267631bbd23f1b8744b9491088eda66ba2ec0e7d2d98841a0098968002000e809fff8080f5f6"
> }

I then tried using the CIP-30 based javascript command with nami in the chrome console to request a transaction signature with the command

> namiAPI.signTx("86a50081825820e34a60ee397dee115b75379af692962dabc085bed002fc0371e578ebd27acd62000d80018282581d60bf1466152d256eb5e8b490c5febc029593f0e9a5b9ee270d75ba35491a004c4b4082583900d9cdd3ead63bd0db91bd83cfa9f3d588bb05a3fb487d5eb62946672cbfcbf21db7267631bbd23f1b8744b9491088eda66ba2ec0e7d2d98841a0098968002000e809fff8080f5f6",
> partialSign=true)

However, I get an error:
"Inputs do not conform to this spec or are otherwise invalid."

The CIP-30 spec from https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0030 is as follows:

> api.signTx(tx: cbor, partialSign: bool = false):
> Promise<cbor<transaction_witness_set>>

I am passing a cbor encoded string (I think), so why is this not working/what should that input look like?

Comment: Typhon Wallet Dapp connector is an alternative to CIP-0030 standard where You don't need to build transactions in the backend with Cardano CLI or build transactions in front-end application after fetching UTXOs. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7658/117

Comment: i am at the same point, did you figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, the key is to add `--cddl-format` to the build command